# How can I increase maximum number of rows that are shown in a SwiftUI picker?

Tags: swiftui, picker

I am trying to create a SwiftUI picker that users can use to select a number from 1000 to 20000 (in increments of 1000. for example 1000,2000,3000 .... ... 20000)

By default the SwiftUI picker can only hold 10 rows of text. How can I allow the SwiftUI picker to contain 20 rows of text?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you wrote something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $value, label: Text("Pick One")) {
            Text("1000").tag(1000)
            Text("2000").tag(2000)
            Text("3000").tag(3000)
            Text("4000").tag(4000)
            Text("5000").tag(5000)
            Text("6000").tag(6000)
            Text("7000").tag(7000)
            Text("8000").tag(8000)
            Text("9000").tag(9000)
            Text("10000").tag(10000)
        }
    }

    @State var value: Int = 1000
}
```

And then you tried to add a row for 11000 and got this error:

```
error: picker.xcplaygroundpage:5:31: error: cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Int>' to expected argument type 'Binding<_>'
            Picker(selection: $value, label: Text("Pick One")) {
                              ^~~~~~
```

The problem is that, due to limitations in the Swift language and in how SwiftUI is implemented, you can only have 10 subviews in a `@ViewBuilder` body.

Here are two ways to work around this.

One way, which is appropriate for your design, is to use `ForEach`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $value, label: Text("Pick One")) {
            ForEach(Array(stride(from: 1000, through: 20000, by: 1000))) { number in
                Text("\(number)").tag(number)
            }
        }
    }

    @State var value: Int = 1000
}
```

The other way, which would be more appropriate if your items didn't follow a simple pattern, is to group your items using `Group`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Picker(selection: $value, label: Text("Pick One")) {
            Group {
                Text("1000").tag(1000)
                Text("2000").tag(2000)
                Text("3000").tag(3000)
                Text("4000").tag(4000)
                Text("5000").tag(5000)
                Text("6000").tag(6000)
                Text("7000").tag(7000)
                Text("8000").tag(8000)
                Text("9000").tag(9000)
                Text("10000").tag(10000)
            }
            Group {
                Text("11000").tag(11000)
                Text("12000").tag(12000)
                Text("13000").tag(13000)
                Text("14000").tag(14000)
                Text("15000").tag(15000)
                Text("16000").tag(16000)
                Text("17000").tag(17000)
                Text("18000").tag(18000)
                Text("19000").tag(19000)
                Text("20000").tag(20000)
            }
        }
    }

    @State var value: Int = 1000
}
```

SwiftUI flattens the `Group` subviews into the `Group`'s parent (in this case, into the `Picker`). Each `Group` can have up to 10 subviews, which can themselves be `Group`s, so by nesting `Group`s you can have arbitrarily many explicit elements in your `Picker`. But I recommend using `ForEach`.

If you want to understand where the 10 subview limit comes from, edit my second example, storing the `Picker` in a variable like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let picker = Picker(selection: $value, label: Text("Pick One")) {
            Group {
            ...
            }
        }
        return picker
    }
}
```

Now option-click the `picker` variable in Xcode to see its inferred type:

[image: inferred type of picker]

Let's reformat that more readably:

```
let picker: Picker<
    Text,
    Int,
    TupleView<(
        Group<TupleView<(
            some View,
            some View,
            some View,
            some View,
            some View,
            some View,
            some View,
            some View,
            some View,
            some View)>>,
        Group<TupleView<(
            some View,
            some View,
            some View,
            some View,
            some View,
            some View,
            some View,
            some View,
            some View,
            some View)>>)>>
```

Wow, that's a big type! SwiftUI uses generic types like this heavily because it is more efficient at runtime. Because these are all `struct` types conforming to `View`, Swift stores this whole `Picker` and all its children in a single contiguous block of memory. That block can start out on the stack and only needs to be copied to the heap when SwiftUI eventually needs to type-erase it or store it long-term. Compare to UIKit, where every view is always separately allocated on the heap on creation.

[`ViewBuilder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder) is the SwiftUI utility that assembles these complex views. Swift transforms the body of each `Group` into a call to `ViewBuilder.buildBlock`, with each view inside the `Group` body as a separate argument to `ViewBuilder.buildBlock`. Each of those arguments could be a separate type (e.g. a `Group` could have some `Text` children and some `Image` children). But Swift doesn't support variadic generics, so `ViewBuilder` has to define a version of `buildBlock` that takes a single view, and a version that takes two views, and a version that takes three views, and so on. It cannot define an infinite number of methods, because then the SwiftUI framework would be infinitely large. So it stops at 10 arguments:

> ```
> static func buildBlock() -> EmptyView
> Builds an empty view from a block containing no statements.
>
> static func buildBlock<Content>(Content) -> Content
> Passes a single view written as a child view through unmodified.
>
> static func buildBlock<C0, C1>(C0, C1) -> TupleView<(C0, C1)>
> static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2>(C0, C1, C2) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2)>
> static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3>(C0, C1, C2, C3) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3)>
> static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4>(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4)>
> static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5>(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5)>
> static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6>(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6)>
> static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7>(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7)>
> static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8>(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8)>
> static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9>(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9)>
> ```

That's why any view whose content is defined using `ViewBuilder` (which includes `VStack`, `HStack`, `ZStack`, `Picker`, `List`, `Group`, and others) can only have 10 direct subviews.

Comment: Excellent answer. Worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is a good writeup. Is there a quick explanation where the 10 limit comes from? It seems so unlikely to have a limit like that in Swift (unless there's something horrific like 10 hardcoded inits somewhere...)

Comment: I've added an explanation to my answer.