# SwiftUI: Distribute equally multiple VStacks in a VStack with Spacers

Tags: ios, swiftui, vstack

I am trying to build a VStack (container) containing multiple VStacks (element) with each a title and a text. The element VStacks should be distributed equally and have a spacer in between.

For some reason it only works up to 4 element VStack and if I increase then I will get an error

```
Failed to build ContentView.swift
Ambiguous reference to member 'buildingBlock()'
```

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Title 1")
                Text("Text 1")
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Title 2")
                Text("Text 2")
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Title 3")
                Text("Text 3")
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Title 4")
                Text("Text 4")
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Title 5")
                Text("Text 5")
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Title 6")
                Text("Text 6")
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Title 7")
                Text("Text 7")
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Title 8")
                Text("Text 8")
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Title 9")
                Text("Text 9")
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Title 10")
                Text("Text 10")
            }
            Spacer()'
        }
        .background(Color.red)

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `ForEach` pleeeease.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the way SwiftUI is implemented, a view can only have at most 10 direct, explicit subviews. Your top-level `VStack` has 21 direct subviews: the 10 child `VStack`s, and the 11 `Spacer`s around them.

There are various workarounds. If you really need a hard-coded list of subviews, you can use `Group` to make some children indirect:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Group {
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("Title 1")
                    Text("Text 1")
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("Title 2")
                    Text("Text 2")
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("Title 3")
                    Text("Text 3")
                }
            }
            Group {
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("Title 4")
                    Text("Text 4")
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("Title 5")
                    Text("Text 5")
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("Title 6")
                    Text("Text 6")
                }
            }
            Group {
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("Title 7")
                    Text("Text 7")
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("Title 8")
                    Text("Text 8")
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("Title 9")
                    Text("Text 9")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Text("Title 10")
                Text("Text 10")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Here, the top-level `VStack` has 6 direct children: 3 `Group`, 2 `Spacer`, and 1 `VStack`. Each `Group` also has 6 direct children: 3 `VStack` and 3 `Spacer`. No view has more than 10 direct children.

A better approach here is to use `ForEach` to generate the children:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Spacer()
            ForEach(1 ... 10, id: \.self) { i in
                Group {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Title \(i)")
                        Text("Text \(i)")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Now the top-level `VStack` only has two direct subviews: the first `Spacer` and the `ForEach`. The `ForEach` replicates its subview (the `Group`) as many times as needed.

We use the `Group` in this case to allow Swift to infer the type of the `ForEach` body, since the `ForEach` body would otherwise contain two statements (the `VStack` and the `Spacer`) which would prevent Swift from inferring its type.

Comment: thanks for the detailed and very interesting reply. Can you please add a bit more about why SwiftUI only allows 10 direct subviews? I think that is quite limiting.

Comment: I explained it [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57173445/77567). Search for “understand”.